# How to return the generic type of an object inside generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to write a generic service that should work with an object of a specific type. When I write custom implementation of that service, I'd like to object to be variable. Therefore I wanted to override the method that creates that object.

But it won't work. Is it impossible in java to achieve the following?

```
class MyService<T extends Foo> {
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Foo to T
    public T createObject() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public void run() {
        T t = createObject();
        //work with the object
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo;
class CustomService<Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar createObject() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class NewArrayList extends ArrayList {

}

abstract class MyService<T> {
    public abstract T createObject();

    public void run() {
        T t = createObject();
        //work with the object
    }
}

class CustomService extends MyService<NewArrayList> {
    @Override
    public NewArrayList createObject() {
        return new NewArrayList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are providing a default implementation which returns `Foo`. That implementation is not appropriate for subclasses and there is no way to force the subclass to override.

You should have `MyService<T>` and an `abstract T createObject()`. For `Foo` make a `Foo`-specific subclass `FooService<Foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct; you can't do that. Your `T` generic parameter stands for "some class which is a subclass of `Foo`" (where a class is a subclass of itself). You can't assume that it *is* `Foo` exactly, since it might be a class that extends `Foo`.

Think about it: if you had a class `Bar extends Foo` and you did:

```
MyService<Bar> service = ...
Bar myBar = createObject();
```

then your code would create a `Foo` and try to downcast it to a `Bar` — resulting in a `ClassCastException`. The whole point of generics is to avoid incorrect casts and their resulting exceptions.